# When creating a GDNativeLibrary resource, why isn't there an option for the web?

Tags: godot

I'm creating a new GDNativeLibrary resource instance. Here's what the property window looks like:
[image]

Where is the option for the web? Can I even use GDNative with the web export?

Comment: I've moved on to 4.0, but as I recall, GDNative bumps into a lot of web browser's additional (justified) security concerns and requires a special export mode. The three options were Regular, Threads, and GDNative; GDNative had some support, but the worst size and loading times. Perhaps if you switch your export mode, the library option will show up?

Comment: To add some clarity, it's addressed in the documentation here: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/tutorials/export/exporting_for_web.html#export-options